# Emulating a UPnP router

Tags: networking, hardware, router, emulation, upnp

I want to add the option of automatic port forwarding (NAT Traversal) to an application.

I know this can be done using UPnP (specifically the part that communicates with the device presenting itself as an IGD - Internet Gateway Device).

I need to be able to test this port forwarding feature while developing it. And whatever big router system company traffic is routered over

- Doesn't provide UPnP.
- Wouldn't want me messing around with it while it's in live service.

My question is:

**Does anyone know of any software that acts as or emulates a UPnP compatible router?**

Comment: I don't know of a software solution, thus posting as a comment. But you could just buy any cheapo router that supports UPnP and NAT and hook it between your dev machine and your company network. You get to play against a real device, while still on the corpnet.

Comment: Yup - I have a router to test, but it'd be nice to try the software route as well, because I gather UPnP implementation quality varies quite a bit! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use Windows Firewall / Internet Connection Sharing, which [supports](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-1056711.html) UPnp by default. Just setup another machine, with Internet Connection Sharing activated, and you will have a UPnp router.

Also, you could check the UPnp forum for more information [here](http://www.upnp.org/).

Later edit:

You could also try setting up a linux/unix firwall with [igd](http://linux-igd.sourceforge.net/) activated.

Here is a forum post for [ubuntu](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=165288).

And there is a [miniUPnp](http://miniupnp.free.fr/) project too.

Comment: Good idea - I've always ignored ICS!